# Why am I getting wrong values from my joined tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my MySQL schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `total_tax` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_tax2` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=38 ;

INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `date`, `total_tax`, `total`, `total_tax2`) VALUES
(1, '2013-02-14', 6, 100, 21),
(2, '2013-02-18', 6, 100, 21),
(3, '2013-03-01', 6, 100, 21),
(4, '2013-03-07', 6, 100, 21),
(5, '2013-03-28', 6, 100, 21),
(6, '2013-03-28', 6, 100, 21),
(7, '2013-04-04', 6, 100, 21);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

INSERT INTO `purchases` (`id`, `date`, `total`) VALUES
(1, '2013-02-15', 150),
(2, '2013-02-16', 18),
(3, '2013-03-05', 80),
(4, '2013-03-09', 50),
(5, '2013-03-16', 500),
(6, '2013-03-22', 200);
```

And I am trying to get the total values of `sales.total`, `total_tax`, `total_tax2` and `purchases.total` by month by joining table on `date`. I am trying this SQL query:

```
SELECT date_format( sales.date, '%b %Y' ) AS MONTH,
SUM( COALESCE( sales.total, 0 ) ) AS sales,
SUM( COALESCE( purchases.total, 0 ) ) AS purchases,
SUM( COALESCE( total_tax, 0 ) ) AS tax1,
SUM( COALESCE( sales.total_tax2, 0 ) ) AS tax2
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN purchases
ON date_format(purchases.date, '%b %Y' ) = date_format(sales.date, '%b %Y' )
WHERE sales.date >= date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
GROUP BY date_format( purchases.date, '%b %Y' )
ORDER BY date_format( sales.date, '%m' ) ASC
```

and getting results as

```
Feb 2013    400     336     24  84
Mar 2013    1600    3320    96  336
Apr 2013    100     0   6   21
```

Why am I getting these incorrect values?

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aba9/1)

Comment: Just a side note: you do not need to worry about `NULL`s when aggregating with `SUM` they will be skipped automatically.

Comment: I must remark in this question that I was checking your values and values for february seems that are neither correct. Your SQL does not show bad values only on march.

Comment: Why do you say only March is wrong?  Isn't February wrong too?  The first column should be 200, shouldn't it?

Comment: @PM 77-1 I need 0 if there is no value for sales/purchase in that month

Comment: I would `UNION ALL` the two tables together, adding `NULL`s appropriately to separate numeric values horizontally and then do your `SUM` / `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are joining by the month of the dates of your tables, meaning that you are multiplying the rows that you are suming. You either perform the aggregation previously or join by the key of your tables:

```
SELECT S.Month,
       S.sales,
       ISNULL(P.purchases,0) purchases,
       S.tax1,
       S.tax2
FROM (  SELECT  date_format(date, '%b %Y') Month,
                SUM(total) Sales,
                SUM(total_tax) tax1,
                SUM(total_tax2) tax2
        FROM sales
        WHERE sales.date >= date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
        GROUP BY date_format(date, '%b %Y')) S
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  date_format(date, '%b %Y') Month,
                    SUM(total) purchases
            FROM purchases
            GROUP BY date_format(date, '%b %Y')) P
    ON S.Month = P.Month
GROUP BY S.Month
ORDER BY S.Month
```

[Here is the sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aba9/14) with this option.

Comment: . . The query is correct, but the explanation isn't quite right.  The problem isn't the aggregation.  It is the join on months -- this is duplicating rows on either side.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I already saw after checking the query that the problem was that when it is grouping by months, using `left join`, its multiplying the rows, but he is grouping by `sales.month`, why is it doing that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I could've phrase that better, but I was refering to the join actually. I wanted to say that he needed to perform the aggregation previously and then join the results by month.

Comment: Thank you Lemak, Gordon Linoff and DaGLiMiOux I was not sure and was trying to group by both sales and purchases.